# TinyMCE Init advlist_number_styles Not Working

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

I am running TinyMCE 4.1.4 with the advlink plugin.

According to a number of websites (although I saw no official documentation), there is a param in the tinymce.init called advlist_number_styles. For example:

```
advlist_number_styles: [
     { title: "Greek", styles: { listStyleType: "lower-alpha" } },
     { title: "Hebrew", styles: { listStyleType: "hebrew" } }
]
```

However, it doesn't seem to work at all, and generates errors:

On page load there's this error, in the advlist plugin:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.split is not a function
```

And on initiating TinyMCE this (in tinymce.min.js):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isChildOf' of undefined
```

Am I initializing it wrong? I don't see any obvious errors.

Here is an example in context:

```
plugins: [
            "advlist code directionality paste textcolor colorpicker",
        ],
menubar: false,
advlist_number_styles: [
            { styles: { listStyleType: "" }, title: "Standard" }
        ],
toolbar1: "bold italic underline | fontsizeselect fontselect | bullist numlist",
toolbar2: "alignleft aligncenter alignright | ltr rtl | forecolor backcolor | mybutton1 mybutton2 mybutton3 mybutton4 | code",
```